# if I change "runtime library" to MD, should I re-compile ALL MT libraries to MD?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, shared-libraries, settings, static-libraries

I'm using VS2010 and trying to change my project's "runtime library" setting from MT to MD. There are lots of "additional dependency" like below.

> cg.lib;cgGL.lib;cublas.lib;cuda.lib;cudart.lib;cufft.lib;curand.lib;cusparse.lib;glew64.lib;freetype248MT.lib;libpng15.lib;zlib.lib;fbxsdk-2013.1.lib;ftgl.lib

Problem is, do i have to re-compile ALL those MT libraries to MD one by one? Or I don't have to? There's no compile error either way. But I want to be sure if changing libraries to MD is somewhat more reliable/faster or something.

This is a vital issue for me. Please Help! I'll take more questions for accurate answers.

**Edit:**
The real reason I asking this is, I applied hoard on my particle simulation project to make it work faster. But it's slower now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost certainly want to use consistent runtime libraries otherwise all kinds of horrible things can happen. You might get away with it depending on what you are using from the library, but it's probably a bad idea.

MT is multithreaded static and MD is multithreaded dynamic.
The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx) say

> "All modules passed to a given invocation of the linker must have been
>   compiled with the same run-time library compiler option (/MD, /MT,
>   /LD)."